# Oledb behaves differently for .Net 4.0 and .net Framework Client Profile 4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, oledb

Case1 :
When reading an excel using Oledb in .Net Framework Client Profile, the Oledb reads the data in excel ignoring the formatting that is given in excel

Example: 1.98782637 is actual value but after formatting it is displayed as 1.99. 
When I read from my code the value that is read is 1.98782637.

Case2 :
When reading an excel using Oledb in .Net Framework, the Oledb reads the data which is available in excel after formatting

Example: 1.98782637 is actual value but after formatting it is displayed as 1.99. 
When I read from my code the value that is read is 1.99.

Here is the code which I used for both the cases.

```
        DataSet dsoutlier = null;
        OleDbDataAdapter oledbAdapterOutlier = null;
        OleDbConnection oledbConnOutlier = new OleDbConnection();

        string fileName = "C:\\Sample.xlsx";           
       oledbConnOutlier.ConnectionString= "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=0;\'"; 

        if (oledbConnOutlier.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            oledbConnOutlier.Open();
        oledbAdapterOutlier = new OleDbDataAdapter("select F1,F9 from [Sheet1$] where F1 is not null", oledbConnOutlier);
        dsoutlier = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            oledbAdapterOutlier.Fill(dsoutlier);
            int counter = 0;
            foreach (var item in dsoutlier.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                Console.Write(dsoutlier.Tables[0].Rows[counter][0]+"  ");
                Console.WriteLine(dsoutlier.Tables[0].Rows[counter++][1]);


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            oledbConnOutlier.Close();
        }
```

Is there a way to include and ignore formatting in both the cases ?

Comment: You are reading the raw data from the spreadsheet, not the formatted text.

Comment: How to read both raw data and formatted text ? Is there a way to read both ?